# Need to iterate following Section of nested json, no luck yet

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I have this part of json file that I need to convert it to csv..

```
"answers": {"1": {"name": "name","order": "1","sublabels": "{\"prefix\":\"Prefix\",\"first\":\"First Name \\/ Nombre primero\",\"middle\":\"Middle Name\",\"last\":\"Last Name \\/ Nombre de familia\",\"suffix\":\"Suffix\"}","text": "Name / Nombre","type": "control_fullname","answer": {"first": "ABC","last": "DEF"},"prettyFormat": "ABC DEF"}}
```

here is my code the first line itself

```
$Answers = ConvertFrom-Json $_.answers
    foreach($i in $.Answers.1)
    {
        $1 = $._prettyFormat
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you're not having luck with :)

Comment: I added code to the main post..

Comment: What is the expected output? Can you post the value you want from your sample data….

Comment: Inside the foreach loop you constantly overwrite variable `$1`

Comment: here is my full Json

Comment: You haven't provided enough information but here are a couple of things to note. As written your JSON is invalid. You need braces enclosing the entire string. Also if that code snippet is truly the first line of code, then the use of `$_` doesn't make sense, as that usually refers to an item on the pipeline.